# Problem with references

Tags: cross-referencing

The problem is that i have good labels ('good' I mean that they are after caption, I tried with labels in the same line as the caption, and in the next line) and I'm trying to use references to my figures or tables. In one part of the document, they work good. And then, I have one figure after one table, without any thext between them, I have before them text with reference to the table anf to the figure, and pdf shows ref for figure, but for table it shows "??". And the rest figures after that are "??" and one table has working reference, but it is wrong, because table is 6, and reference shows table 2. It isn't my first LaTeX document, I did similar raports with tables and figures before, I check the document and I don't know what is going on.

This is my preambule:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[OT4]{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\linespread{1.3}
\renewcommand*{\figurename}{Rys.} 
\renewcommand*{\tablename}{Tab.}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font={footnotesize}}
```

And the last working figure and not working table:

```
Wyniki zostaly przedstawione w tabeli \ref{czulosc} oraz na rysunku \ref{st}. 

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{caption} 
\label{czulosc}
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
My table here
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{media}
\caption{caption}
\label{st}
\end{figure}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: We'd really like a complete example we can copy-paste to reproduce the problem. There is nothing obviously wrong with the code you've posted.

Comment: Maybe I should uplod somewhere my work, because it is long document with tables and figures. I have it on dropbox, so I can share a folder with this document. Is it a good solution?

Comment: A real [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) will be better, it will take half an hour to do so though. But you might find the reason yourself, and this is a great feeling :-) If not, we will have just the right stuff to do some testing and provide a solution to your personal problem.

Comment: I added an answer with explanation, what I did wrong. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by the OP putting their files in unexpected places.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your concern. I solved the problem. It looks like there wasn't any problem with the document structure and latex code, but with my files! When I started writing this document in LaTeX, a haven't mark the option in TeXmaker, that every "build" files would go to new folder "build", and in some time, when I was working on other documents, I marked this option. And in that case, I had some build files in the special folder, and outside it, where the tex file was. When I wanted to share with you this document, I did the new folder on my dropbox, copy-paste the old folder, and I have deleted not important files, including this build files outside buil folder. My curiosity pushed me to try, if the document will work. And I didn't see any log messages with undefined references... So, in conclusion, it was my fault. The problem wasn't in the code, but outside the code. Thank you very much for your attention again.